# install pip module for all windows users on PC

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I added the pip module in VScode and can install modules for myself using pip but they install into my private path.
Can I tell visual-code / pip to install certain modules on the machine for all users instead?
I have a few modules that I need all users to have by default
Thanks

Comment: have you tried running pip as admin?